# How to mount and swap storage

Tags: mount, swap

I got a Linux machine of 1TB. The storage structure is like this:

```
/dev/xvda1            9.8G  1.9G  7.8G  20% /. 

tmpfs                  30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm. 

/dev/nvme0n1          1.8T   20G  1.6T   2% /local.
```

Now I have my processes run on `/tmp` folder and my application is failing because there is not enough memory present on device.

How do I get the storage in `/local` directory to `/` directory.

Comment: Are you needing to create a new swap file in a different location?

Comment: /dev/xvda1            9.8G  1.9G  7.8G  20% / 

is getting used when i try to use the /tmp directory, not allowing the application to use the total storage of the device.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu? What version?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directory under `/` like so:

```
sudo mkdir /new_local
```

Then bind the `/local` directory to it like so:

```
sudo mount --bind /local /new_local
```

This way all the space and contents of `/local` will be accessible under `/new_local`

---

If however your goal is to extend the storage space on `/tmp` using the available space on `/local` then please follow the two steps below:

First, create a directory under `/local` like so:

```
sudo mkdir /local/new_tmp
```

Then, bind it to `/tmp` like so:

```
sudo mount --bind /local/new_tmp /tmp
```

This way all the available free space under `/local` will be given to `/tmp`

Comment: but how will /tmp get the storage then?

Comment: @Rahul I answered your question " How do I get the storage in /local directory to / directory. ". If you want the extend `/tmp` space, I will update the answer for that. One moment please.