# Failed to move /home directory to a new partition?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, xubuntu, fstab, home-directory

Running Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit on a system with 2 hard drives. System is dual boot: Win-10 & Xubuntu. The PC has 2 disk drives: a small boot flash drive with a 14.7 Gb Partition for Linux and a 169 Gb partition for Linux on the 2nd data drive.

Ubuntu installed itself completely to the 14.7 Gb Partition & that's where the $Home directory was mounted at `/`.  Both OSes booted fine but the 2nd drive was left as *169 GB: unallocated space*. Used GParted boot disk to set this 169 Gb as a primary partition formatted ext4 following the article [Partitioning/Home/Moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to move my home to the new home on the "big" 169 GB partition.

All seemed to go well but then the 169 Gb partition "disappeared".  I can still find it under `blkid`:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT

NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL         SIZE MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs              27.1M /snap/snapd/7264
loop1  squashfs                55M /snap/core18/1754
loop2  squashfs                55M /snap/core18/1705
loop3  squashfs              54.8M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop4  squashfs              62.1M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop5  squashfs              17.9M /snap/gedit/537
loop6  squashfs               7.7M /snap/gedit/371
loop7  squashfs             160.2M /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop8  squashfs                27M /snap/snapd/6953
sda                         119.2G 
├─sda1 ntfs     SSHD_boot    91.1G 
├─sda2 ntfs                   834M 
├─sda3                          1K 
├─sda5 swap                  12.6G 
└─sda6 ext4                  14.8G /
sdb                         931.5G 
├─sdb1 ntfs     Sam 860 Evo 762.6G 
└─sdb2 ext4     Sam Evo P2    169G /home
```

But when I try to mount it per my `fstab`, it simply isn't mounted.  It is the sdb2 ext4 at the bottom of the listing.
Here's my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
# original filesystem
UUID=377ba606-019e-4408-a5a8-832bab58f3bc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# new 169 Gb partition label Sam Evo P2 
UUID=295d54bd-8508-4dd8-83dc-80f950028d8d /home     ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The wiki "Moving Home" article seems to neglect mentioning exactly how to mount both partitions.  The OS boot partition is under: sda6 while the new `/home` is under sdb2.

Any suggestions on how I can complete the move and load my new $Home partition?

---

Responding to the question about how I know my new partition is not mounted

Below is my Desktop. Before I edited fstab, it showed 3 filesystems: "Sam Evo P2" which is my 1TB Samsung Evo 860 drive: Partition 2 {ext4}. This partition was mounted under `/home`.  It also showed the others: Sam 860 Evo + SSHD_boot } both of these are working fine as NTFS Windows partitions.

Now as you can see the "Sam Evo P2" is gone and hovering over File System shows I've used 98% of the 15.6 Gb.

[image: file system no space]

However if I go into the filesystem  `/home/john` then it appears that I've actually mounted that 169Gb partition {here it says 177.5 Gb}.

[image: file system with space]

Note that `/old_home` is a copy of my home directory from when I only mounted the 15.6 Gb partition.  Eventually I should delete it if my system works.  Does this mean that my system is actually working???

Comment: Your fstab shows it should be mounted.  And your lsblk shows it mounted. Are you booted into your install? You cannot mount it again if already mounted.

Comment: Your `lsblk`-output shows `sdb2` mounted at `/home`, why do you think it's not mounted? What do you mean with `the 169 Gb partition "disappeared"`?

Comment: Hi,  Thanks a lot.  I appended my comment to show new info & to try to answer your question.

Comment: Looks fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, it does look like it worked.  I may move "old_home" to the new partition for a while to free up some space on my boot drive partition.

Comment: If you used the `rsync`-command according to the guide you used, your data should exist in the new partition already, since your background image and theme are present it looks like you don't need to do that.

Comment: Did you solve this? It might be helpful if you could post an answer explaining what happened

Comment: An update.  I believe the addition of the new hard drive and the moving of the home partition was sucessful.  As discussed I used the Ubuntu article at the top to perform the move.  I thus merged the space from the new hard drive into my home partition so Ubuntu has a lot more space.